# python-docx throwing exit code error -1073741819 (0xC0000005) from pycharm on windows 10

Tags: flask, windows-10, pycharm, python-docx, python-3.7

I am having some difficulty getting python-docx to work with my flask app. Initially the problem was getting lxml installed so I could pip install python-docx. I downloaded the file

```
lxml-4.2.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

and have it sitting in the project root folder. I tried at first specifying the full path to the file but after getting the above error I uninstalled and reinstalled using simply the file name (pip was the installer). Both ways allowed me to install the library form the file and subsequently python-docx but as soon as I insert the import statememt "from docx import Document" running the program produces the exit code from the title.

I am running pycharm2.7 on windows 10 and using python3.7

The full error when running the app is

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

*** EDIT *** Same result when trying ***** "from lxml import etree" *****

Comment: if you skip the app, what happens when you go to a python interpreter and type `from docx import Document` ? Seems like the error is masked.

Comment: it produces the same exit code

Comment: Try `import lxml` instead. I bet you get the same. Merely having a wheel file present doesn't install it. Google installing lxml on windows with pycharm.

Comment: I thought pip would take care of the installation but maybe you are right

Comment: seems to be a windows bug. Trying to install and run on ubuntu server atm